# Spin UIPickerView Component using Timer

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swift3

I want to spin all `UIPickerView` Component like lottery wheel using timer in swift. I have a 3 component in `UIPickerView` want to spin all the components same on same time. I am suing below code to spin the component in `UIPickerView`:

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(scrollRandomly), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);

@objc func scrollRandomly() {

    let row:Int = Int(arc4random() % 9);
    let row1:Int = Int(arc4random() % 9);
    let row2:Int = Int(arc4random() % 9);

    pickerView.selectRow(row, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    pickerView.selectRow(row1, inComponent: 1, animated: true)
    pickerView.selectRow(row2, inComponent: 2, animated: true)


}
```

Thanks,
Rushabh

Comment: So... what is you question?

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Reference link : https://github.com/MaorS/iOS-Proj-CasinoGame

Comment: Again, this is not a question. What problems are you facing?

Comment: @AndreasOetjen I can't rotate componant for 10 second just how can I rotate components programatically

Answer (score 0):

I use this extension

```
self.view.beginRotating()
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
    self.view.stopRotating()
}
```

_

```
fileprivate var RotatingObjectHandle: UInt8 = 0
fileprivate var RotationCycleHandler: UInt8 = 0


extension UIView {
    
    private var shouldStopRotating: Bool {
        
        get {
            
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &RotationCycleHandler) as? Bool ?? false
        }
        set {
            
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &RotationCycleHandler, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
    
    private(set) var isRotating: Bool {
        
        get {
            
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &RotatingObjectHandle) as? Bool ?? false
        }
        set {
            
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &RotatingObjectHandle, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
    
    
    func beginRotating() {
        
        guard !self.isRotating else { return }
        
        self.isRotating = true
        self.shouldStopRotating = false
        self.rotate()
    }
    
    
    private func rotate() {
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.65, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            self.transform = self.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi))
        }, completion: { _ in
            
            if !self.shouldStopRotating {
                
                self.rotate()
            } else {
                
                self.isRotating = false
                self.shouldStopRotating = false
            }
        })
    }
    
    
    func stopRotating() {
        
        self.shouldStopRotating = true
    }
 }
```